# Is it possible to use borland component in visual studio c++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Is it possible to use component from c++ builder 2010 in visual studio 2010 c++? For example I made little program in c++ builder that send email, for those purpose I used smtp component, and now want to do all same in the visual studio (cause I have other code in visual studio that need those functionality), cause visual studio don't have those component, I just want to use (migrate) existing component from c++ builder in visual studio. How to do that? Is it possible to make that?

OS: Win 7, 64

Answer (score 1):

Make it a com component in Borland C++ and then reference it.

I'd be shocked if you can't find an SMTP thingy for Visual C++.

Comment: Or a plain DLL that you can import into VC++.

Comment: Thank's for answer, :) it's not heavy to find smtp component ... it's just hard me to make thing work propertly, so just want to use something which know how works, ...